# React , custom hook slow render

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, react-navigation, react-forms

Hello I made a custom hook that goes hand in hand with a component for generic forms, however, I notice that it is slow when the state changes.

```
#customHook
export const useFormController = (meta) => {
  const { setVisible, setLoading } = useContext(FeedBackContext);
  const itemsRef = useRef([]);
  const {
    control,
    setValue,
    handleSubmit,
    formState: { errors },
  } = useForm<Partial<any>>({
    mode: "onBlur",
    shouldUnregister: true,
    resolver: yupResolver(meta.validation),
  });

  const onRef = function (input) {
    this.itemsRef.current[this.index] = input;
  };

  const onSubmit = (data: any) => {
    if(meta.onSubmit){
      meta.onSubmit(data);
    }else{
      setVisible(true);
      setLoading(true);
      meta.service.submit(data);
    }
  };

  const isJsonEmpty = (val = {}) => {
    return Object.keys(val).length == 0;
  };
  const onSubmitIditing = function () {
    let index = ++this.index;
    if (isJsonEmpty(errors) && this.end) {
      handleSubmit(onSubmit)();
    } else if (!this.end) {
      this.itemsRef.current[index]._root.focus();
    }
  };
  const setFields = (json) => {
    const items = Object.keys(json);
    const values = Object.values(json)
    console.log('Cambiando fields en formControllser...', json)
    for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
      //console.log('Cambiando valores...', items[i], values[i])

      setValue(items[i], values[i], { shouldValidate: true })
    }
  }


  const getItems = () => {
    console.log('Meta namess', meta.names, meta);

    if (!meta && !meta.names) return [];

    return meta.names.map(function (item, index) {
      const isEnd =
        meta.options && meta.options[item] && meta.options[item].end
          ? true
          : false;

      const isSecure =
        meta.options && meta.options[item] && meta.options[item].secure
          ? true
          : false;

      const label = meta.alias ? meta.alias[item] : item;
      const visible = meta.invisibles ? (meta.invisibles[item] ? false : true) : true;
      const def = meta.defaults ? meta.defaults[item] : "";

      const disabled = (val) => {
        const b = meta.disableds ? (meta.disableds[item] ? true : false) : false;
        return b;
      }

      return {
        name: item,
        label: label,
        disabled: disabled,
        onRef: onRef.bind({ itemsRef: itemsRef, index: index }),
        onSubmitEditing: onSubmitIditing.bind({
          itemsRef: itemsRef,
          index: index,
          end: isEnd,
          errors: errors,
        }),
        visible: visible,
        setFields,
        defaultValue: def,
        errors: errors,
        secureTextEntry: isSecure,
        styles: styles,
        control: control,
        options: meta.options[item] ? meta.options[item] : null,
      };
    });
  }

  const getData = useMemo(() => {
    console.log('Get data calback v2', meta);
    return {
      handleSubmit,
      items: getItems(),
      onSubmit,
      errors,
      setFields
    };
  }, [meta])


  return getData;
};




export const Client: React.FC<any> = React.memo(({ navigation, route }) => {


  const {
    alias,
    defaults,
    ubigeoSeleccionado,
    setUbigeoSeleccionado,
    editable,
    inputLabel,
    search,
    getDisabled,
    getInvisibles,
    getAlias,
    getDefaults,
    disableds,
    invisibles,
    searchVisible,
    idTypeDocument,
    currentTypeDocument,
    allTypeDocuments,
    onValueChange,
    onChangeText } = useContext(CreateClientContext);
  const [mode, setMode] = useState(() => {
    return route?.params?.mode;
  })
  const [client, setClient] = useState(() => {
    return route?.params?.client;
  })
  const { dispatchClient } = useContext(GlobalContext);
  const clientService = useClientService();
  const ref = useRef(0);
  const options = useMemo(() => {

    return {
      names: ["ane_numdoc", "ane_razsoc", "ane_alias", "ane_email", "ane_tel", "ane_tel2", "ane_dir"],
      validation: clientValidation,
        alias: alias,
        defaults: defaults,
        disableds: disableds,
        service: {
          submit: (data) => {
            const parse = { ...data, ubigeo_id: ubigeoSeleccionado.ubi_id, ane_tipo_cp: 2, ane_tipdoc: currentTypeDocument.id }
            if (mode == "update") {
              //console.log('Actualizando...', client.id, parse);
              clientService.updateById(client.id, parse)
                .then(ok => {
                  Alert.alert('Actualizaciòn de cliente', "Cliente Actualizado")
                  dispatchClient({
                    type: 'create',
                    payload: ok
                  });

                  setTimeout(() => {
                    navigation.navigate('App', {
                      screen: "Clients"
                    })
                  }, 500)

                }).catch(e => {
                  Alert.alert('Actualizaciòn de cliente', "No se pudo actualizar")
                })

            } else {
              clientService.create(parse)
                .then(ok => {
                  dispatchClient({
                    type: 'create',
                    payload: ok
                  });
                  Alert.alert('Cliente', "Cliente creado")

                  setTimeout(() => {
                    navigation.navigate('App', {
                      screen: "Clients"
                    })
                  }, 500)
                })
                .catch(e => {
                  (e);
                  Alert.alert('Error', "No se pudo crear el cliente")
                })
            }
          }
        },
        invisibles: invisibles,
        options: {
          ane_dir: {
            end: true
          },
        }
    }

  }, [getDisabled,
    getInvisibles,
    getAlias,
    getDefaults])
  const { items, handleSubmit, onSubmit, errors, setFields } = useFormController(options);

  useEffect(() => {
    ref.current++;
  })

  useEffect(() => {
    if (route.params) {
      console.log('Ref current', ref.current);
      setMode(route.params.mode);
      setClient(route.params.client);
    }
  }, [route.params])
  useEffect(() => {
    // console.log('Mode', mode, client.id);
    if (mode == "update" && client) {
      console.log('cambiando fields'), ref;
      setFields(client)
    }
  }, [mode, client])

  // useEffect(()=>{

  // },[instanceDocument])

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('Cambiando cliente...', mode, client);
    console.log(ref.current);
  }, [client])

  useEffect(() => {
    //Creación
    console.log('set defaults..', ref.current);
    if (Object.keys(defaults).length > 0) {
      setFields(defaults)
    }
  }, [getDefaults])
  console.log('Current', ref.current);
  return (
    <StyleProvider style={getTheme(material)}>
      <Container style={{ backgroundColor: "#FAF9FE" }}>
        <Content style={GlobalStyles.mainContainer}>
          <Text style={GlobalStyles.subTitle}>Cliente</Text>
          <PickerSearch
          search={search}
          editable={editable}
          style={styles}
            searchVisible={searchVisible}
          placeholder={inputLabel}
          pickerItems={allTypeDocuments}
          onValueChange={onValueChange}
            selectedValue={idTypeDocument}
          onChangeText={onChangeText}
          ></PickerSearch>

          <FormListController
              // top={<Top />}
              items={items}
              style={GlobalStyles}
            ></FormListController>

          <Bottom
            ubigeoSeleccionado={ubigeoSeleccionado}
        setUbigeoSeleccionado={setUbigeoSeleccionado}
        onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}
        />



        </Content>
        <AppFooter2 navigation={navigation} />
      </Container>
    </StyleProvider>
  );
});

export const FormListController: React.FC<any> = React.memo(({ children, items = [], style, top = null, bottom = null }) => {

  console.log('%c Form list controlllser...', "background-color:#ccc");
  console.log('items', items)
  return (
    <>
      <Form style={!!style.form ? style.form : style.formContainer}>
        {top}
        {items.map((item: any, index) => {

          return <FormItemController {...item} key={index} />;

        })}
        
        {bottom}

      </Form>
    </>
  );
});


export const FormItemController: React.FC<any> = React.memo((props: any) => {
  console.log('Form item controller print', props)
  if (props.visible) {
    return (
      <>
        <Controller
          control={props.control}
          render={
            ({ field: { onChange, onBlur, value } }) => {

              return (
                <Item regular style={props.styles.item}>
                  <Label style={props.styles.label}>{props.label}</Label>
                  <Input
                    onBlur={onBlur}
                    disabled={props.disabled(value)}
                    onChangeText={(value) => onChange(value)}
                    secureTextEntry={props.secureTextEntry}
                    onSubmitEditing={props.onSubmitEditing}
                    value={value}
                    ref={props.onRef}
                  />
                </Item>
              )
            }

          }

          defaultValue={props.defaultValue}
          name={props.name}
        />
        {props.errors && props.errors[props.name] && (
          <TextError value={props.errors[props.name].message} />
        )}
        {/* {props.options && props.options.errorEmpty && props.errors[""] && (
          <TextError value={props.errors[""].message} />
        )} */}
      </>
    );
  }
  else {
    return <></>
  }
});
```

I use the same component to create and edit a client, but when editing and viewing the FormItemController the logs time span is less than 1 second, however it is not rendered until after 8 or 10 seconds.

This is the output of my logs.

```
Update cliente...  500ms 

set defaults.. 77
Client num render 77
Client num render 78
Client num render 79
Client num render 80
Client num render 81
Client num render 82
Client num render 83
Client num render 84
Client num render 85
Client num render 86
Client num render 87
Client num render 88
Client num render 89
Client num render 90
Client num render 91
Client num render 92
Client num render 93
Client num render 94
Client num render 95
Client num render 96
Client num render 97
Client num render 98
Client num render 99
Client num render 100  (6-8 seg)
```

the problem I have is when I edit, when I use the forms to create I have no problems, I do not find the bottleneck to improve and prevent it from being slow.

Answer (score 0):

After trying several options, I realized that when passing the setValue, I was sending several nulls and objects that did not go with the form, filtering this data, made the final rendering pass from 8 seconds to less than 1 second

```
  const setFields = (json) => {
    const items = Object.keys(json);
    const values = Object.values(json)
    for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
      if (!!values[i] && typeof values[i] != 'object') {
        setValue(items[i], values[i])
      }

    }
  }
```

Comment: Just a small possible code improvement: iterate over `Object.entries(json)` instead of grabbing the keys and values separately.

Comment: thanks, i'm still optimizing this code